# Firebase cli app distribuiton is too slow. How can I speed it up?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface

I have internet which has upload speed of **600Mbit** per second. I have been using firebase cli(*version 11.16.0*) to upload **apk and ipa** app files to firebase. But their size is around 200 MB. However uploading them to firebase takes 1.5 to 2 minutes. Is there any other option to speed it up. Is the bottleneck Google? Is there a premium service of Google to increase my bandwith?

Comment: Raw speed has little to do with real performance. A database that could accept 600 Mbits/sec would be very expensive.

Comment: My uploads last ranging from 47 sec to 2 min. Sizes of my files are almost the same. What do you think the cause of this deviation of upload times? Does it depend on load of firebase database?

Comment: I suggest reaching out with the appropriate [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) regarding your concern if there is a premium service of Google.